# Call Parameter in an Array - Currently Returning Null

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following:

```
require 'my-settings.php';

echo '>>'.$curAppId.'<<';

    $content = array(
                     "en" => 'English Message'
                     );

    $fields = array(
                    'app_id' => $curAppId,
                    'included_segments' => array('All'),
                    'data' => array("foo" => "bar"),
                    'contents' => $content
                    );

    $fields = json_encode($fields);
    print("\nJSON sent:\n");
```

It is outputting the following:

```
>>XXXX<<

JSON sent: {"app_id":null,"included_segments":["All"],"data":{"foo":"bar"},"contents":{"en":"English Message"}}
```

$curAppId has the value XXXX set in the file my-settings.php. In fact it is being echod correctly. But in the array it is being seen as null.

Can you please help?

Comment: `$currApId` != `$curApId`. Over.

Comment: When you ask a question about an error **ALWAYS** include the **error log**. Add `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the top of your `php` script, what does it return?

Comment: @u_mulder sorry it's a typo here. I fixed it but still returns as null

Comment: Then you obviously show us not all codes. As provided code works fine: https://3v4l.org/CEh6v

Comment: Sily mistake, code was in a function except for the require (which was outside).

Answer (score 0):

You have a spelling mistake You referred to $curAppId then in the array you referred to $currAppId. I fixed the spelling mistake below

```
require 'my-settings.php';

echo '>>'.$curAppId.'<<';
$content = array(
                 "en" => 'English Message'
                 );

$fields = array(
                'app_id' => $curApId, //Had two r's
                'included_segments' => array('All'),
                'data' => array("foo" => "bar"),
                'contents' => $content
                );

$fields = json_encode($fields);
print("\nJSON sent:\n");
```

> This is what we call a programmers nightmare, but in your case an
>   error would of told you the problem ^,^

Comment: Sorry it's a typo I did here, but it still returned as null after fixing. Editing my original post.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo:

```
'app_id' => $curAppId,
```